# Change enumerate numbering scheme in beamer without losing bullets

Tags: beamer, enumerate

I'm changing the numbering scheme for some (but not all) enumerate lists while using beamer (with Warsaw), using `\begin{enumerate}[a]`. While this works in principle, the new "numbers" a, b, c, ... get printed without bullet style, as plain (blue) text. Is there a way to preserve the bullet style you get for the default enumerate?

Edit: Added minimal working example below.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Default has bullets (in beamer/Warsaw):
\begin{enumerate}
\item Some item
\item another item
\end{enumerate}
But alphabetical numbering via enumerate parameter looks ugly:
\begin{enumerate}[a]
\item Some item
\item another item
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Comment: Do you mean `\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\textbullet\alph{enumi}}`. Please add some working Code (See M(inimal)W(orking)E(xample)).

Comment: Thanks, that did it after a little tweaking to make it work for my case - ended up using `\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\alph{enumii}}` (since it was for a sublist) and `\begin{enumerate}`.

Comment: @Bobyandbob Sounds like your comment solved the problem. Would you like to write an answer?

Comment: Please clarify your question and add some more details. A [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) and  maybe an image(output, that you want to achive) would be helpful. @samcarter Then i can write an answer, otherwise the question is not relevant to others and should be closed.

Comment: Sorry for coming back so late, added MWE.